# C++ String ASCII Communication to SerialCOM with VB example

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, serial-port, ascii

I have a VB 5.0 code that does what I need, but I need to implement it in Visual Studio C++ (2013), the thing is that I'm not getting there, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, so I'll show you some code (VB vs C++ - mine) and hope someone is able to help.

For now, thank you for reading this.

I've tried to send the string in very different formats and I think that I finally got it, in how to send, the problem still is reading the answer, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
The machine returns (I think 2 bytes) and they are START OF HEADING and ?, I can see it by printing in the console the numbers 1 and 63.

I'll just leave some code.

For asking the current temperature the VB program is:

```
Private Sub cmdGetTemperaturePV_Click()

  If MSComm.PortOpen Then
    MSComm.Output = Chr(1) & Chr(0) & Chr(0) & Chr(1) & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
    txtMsg(1).Text = "1,0,0,1,13,10"
    txtPVTemperature.Text = ""
  Else
    txtMsg(1).Text = "COM Port OFF"
    Beep
  End If

End Sub
```

And mine(C++) is:

```
String^ a1 = "\x1";
String^ a2 = "\x0";
String^ a3 = "\x0";
String^ a4 = "\x1";
String^ a5 = "\xD";
String^ a6 = "\xA";
String^ enviar = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6;

this->serialPort1->Write(enviar);
```

By using the program "Hercules" I can simulate the reception of the machine and I can see that I'm sending exactly the same thing as the VB program.
Now I think that the problem is receiving, so about that, there's this:

```
Private Sub tmrRun_Timer()

  Dim i As Integer
  Dim apt As Byte, B1 As Byte, B2 As Byte
  Dim stx As String



  If MSComm.PortOpen Then
    If MSComm.InBufferCount >= 6 Then
      stx = MSComm.Input
      stx = Right(stx, 6)
      txtMsg(2).Text = ""
      For i = 1 To Len(stx)
        txtMsg(2).Text = txtMsg(2).Text & Asc(Mid(stx, i, 1)) & ","
      Next i
      txtMsg(2).Text = Left(txtMsg(2).Text, Len(txtMsg(2).Text) - 1)

      apt = Asc(Left(stx, 1))
      B1 = Asc(Mid(stx, 2, 1))
      B2 = Asc(Mid(stx, 3, 1))

      Select Case apt
        Case 1:
          txtPVTemperature.Text = Format(0.1 * GetInt(B1, B2), "0.0")
        Case 2:
          txtSPTemperature.Text = Format(0.1 * GetInt(B1, B2), "0.0")
        Case 3:

        Case 4:
          txtPVHumidity.Text = Format(0.1 * GetInt(B1, B2), "0.0")
        Case 5:
          txtSPHumidity.Text = Format(0.1 * GetInt(B1, B2), "0.0")
        Case 6:

        Case 7:
        Case 8:
        Case 9:
          If Asc(Mid(stx, 2, 1)) > 0 Then
            txtChamber.Text = "ON"
          Else
            txtChamber.Text = "OFF"
          End If

        Case 10:
          txtEvents.Text = GetInt(B1, B2)
        Case 11:

        Case 12:
          txtInputs.Text = "1..8 = " & B1 & "    9..16 = " & B2

        Case 13:
          txtAlarms1.Text = " 1.. 8 = " & B1 & "     9..16 = " & B2
        Case 14:
          txtAlarms2.Text = "17..24 = " & B1 & "    25..32 = " & B2

      End Select
    End If
  End If

End Sub
```

And I'm trying many different things, the best I got (the one that led me to 1 and 63) is this:

```
{
        String^ rec;

        if (this->serialPort1->IsOpen)
        {
            this->textBox1->Text = String::Empty;

            try
            {
                rec = this->serialPort1->ReadExisting();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException^)
            {
                this->textBox2->Text = "Timeout";
            }
        }

        this->textBox1->Text = rec;

        char aux[100];

        if (rec == String::Empty)
            this->textBox2->Text = "String Empty";
        else
        {
            std::string rec1 = marshal_as<std::string>(rec);

            strcpy(aux, rec1.c_str());


            int a, b, c, d, e1, f;

            printf("String received: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if (aux[i] == 0)
                    break;
                printf("%ld ", aux[i]);
                if (i == 0)
                    a = aux[i];
                if (i == 1)
                    b = aux[i];
                if (i == 2)
                    c = aux[i];
                if (i == 3)
                    d = aux[i];
                if (i == 4)
                    e1 = aux[i];
                if (i == 5)
                    f = aux[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm expecting to receive a 6 byte string and It's not happening.

I'm so sorry for the long post, but I think this way I can be more specific.

Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Try waiting for 6 bytes to be in the receive buffer: `while (6 != this->serialPort1->BytesToRead)....`

Comment: Thank you for replying, I didn't actually try that. Unfortunately I can only test that next Monday.
I'll give some reply later. Thank you again!

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I've tried and didn't quite work, the program just stops running.
With the command you suggested I'm trying to read how many bytes there is in the buffer, and trying to see where the problem is. Again thank you for your suggestion